# Does Integrated Security=SSPI require a Windows user in the Administrators group?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I'm having issues testing my c# WinForms application with a normal user and a sql express database. I think the SSPI in the connection string is the problem.

Edit: The issue is that the connection won't open. Here is the exception I get when logged in as normal user (I don't get this as an admin user where it opens correctly).

> Login failed for user 'AsusWin7-64\SomeUser'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

Comment: The answer to your question is "No". However, it's impossible to offer any advice on what the problem might be, because you didn't tell us what the problem is - "I'm having issues testing" without telling us what the issues are is meaningless. Please [edit] your question to provide more information. As it is now, it's not a real question.

Comment: @Ken -- added additional information.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question posed in the title is no, SSPI doesn't require a Windows users in the Admin group. What is the exact nature of the failure/error you are experiencing?

**EDIT: ** You will need to ensure your SQL Express database is configured to accept Windows Integrated authentication, and then define that local machine user into the database with permission(s) to the appropriate database(s), table(s), and procedure(s).

Comment: +1. it simply requires user to be configured in SQL to have access, admins have access because local admins group is normally added to have full access to each SQL database on given server.

Comment: My app is shrink wrap for non-technical users and I will never know any normal users ahead of time, and there never will be a DBA to set up permissions. My install will not be able to set up users. Any suggestions for normal users appreciated. Is there a way to set up sql express security for any user?

Comment: Ugh, unfortunately there aren't a great deal of options if you have no administration or configuration tool. You might want (have) to consider creating a single SQL Server user and use that identity for your app's data access, which can then be encoded into the application. Not by any means ideal, but given your constraints it may be your only option.

Comment: Figured it out after a few hours. I took the approach of adding the "BUILTIN/Users" login to my database, with read/write permissions. Now Integrated Security=SSPI is working for normal user.